# How to prevent access to URL if event is empty?

Tags: php, joomla

I need to prevent the Access to this File if the `ohanah_event_id` is not set.
How can I accomplish this?

```
<?php

/**
 * @package     Ohanah
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2012 - 2016 Beyounic SA. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU GPLv3 <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 * @link        http://www.beyounic.com
 */

class ComOhanahViewTicketHtml extends ComOhanahViewHtml
{
    protected function _fetchData(KViewContext $context)
    {
        parent::_fetchData($context);

        if ($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id) {
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $translator = $this->getObject('translator');

            $doc->setTitle($translator->translate('COM_OHANAH_TICKET') . ' - ' . $context->data->ticket->event->title);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried another condition inside the if ?  with if (empty($context)) { header (location ....)} else {your function continue}

Comment: @Robin no, because I sadly don't have much knowledge of PHP :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
class ComOhanahViewTicketHtml extends ComOhanahViewHtml
{
    protected function _fetchData(KViewContext $context)
    {
        parent::_fetchData($context);
        if(!empty($context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id)){
        $context->data->ticket->ohanah_event_id;
            $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $translator = $this->getObject('translator');

            $doc->setTitle($translator->translate('COM_OHANAH_TICKET') . ' - ' . $context->data->ticket->event->title);
        }
        else {
       return false;}
    }
}
?>
```

you can try like that with a condition and !empty, and if it's empty you return false to the function